# meteor raix:push error 8

Tags: ios, meteor

I'm stuggling with meteor and push messages. i followed this guide: http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

so far when i test my certificates it works but when i deploy the app on my iphone and i try to send a push message i got: Got error code 8 for token [my device token]

I searched google for this problem but i didn't find any solution. can anyone please help me with this?

thanks in advance